# Закрытие нескольких модальных окон

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios7, xcode6.3

Имеется контроллер А (`TableViewController`), по нажатию на ячейку мы переходим в контроллер Б (`ViewController`), все это лежит в `Navigation Controller`. В контроллере Б мы можем перейти по ссылке, тогда вызовется этот код, и мы модально добавим новый контроллер Б, так мы можем добавить много модальных view:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
DetailViewController *relatedNews = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:DetailViewControllerID];
relatedNews.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
relatedNews.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:relatedNews];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemStop
                                                                            target:self
                                                                           action:@selector(backPressed)];
relatedNews.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
[[self.navigationController topViewController] presentViewController:navController
                                                            animated:YES
                                                          completion:nil];


-(void) backPressed {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку будет вызываться `dismissViewControllerAnimated`, который будет закрывать наше модальное окно. А как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на эту кнопку мы закрыли все наши модальные окна и вернулись к самому первому контролеру Б, который был вызван пуш сегвеем. Так вообще сделать можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
UIViewController *vc = self.presentingViewController;
while (vc.presentingViewController) {
    vc = vc.presentingViewController;
}
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

С помощью цикла ты доберешься до самого первого контроллера, а вызов `dismissViewControllerAnimated` на нем сбросит весь стек. Не гарантирую, что будет работать, но должно

Comment: Спасибо, немного исправил, что бы отрабатывало когда 1 модальное окно

Comment: @Дмитрий не стесняйтесь отмечать ответ как принятый:)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так немного поправил, что бы отрабатывало когда всего 1 раз вызывали модальное окно:

```
UIViewController *vc = self.presentingViewController;
while (vc.presentingViewController) {
    vc = vc.presentingViewController;
}
if(!vc) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
} else {
    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```